# HTTP response is empty

Tags: android, json, node.js, okhttp

I am using okHTTP to make an https call to a nodejs/express server. The server returns a json string

```
{"result" : true}
```

This json string is shown as {"result":true} in the browser, however when I try to read the response using OkHTTp, I get the following response:

```
 <h1>Not Found</h1>
 <h2></h2>
 <pre></pre>
```

There is no json response to be found. Here is the Okhttp code I am using.

```
 public static void sendCredentialsWithPost(LinkedHashMap<String, String> data, String serverUrl, Callback callback) {

        Object[] keys = data.keySet().toArray();

        FormBody.Builder formBodyBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();

        for(Object k : keys) {
            String key = (String) k;
            formBodyBuilder.add(key, data.get(key).toString());
        }

        RequestBody formBody = formBodyBuilder.build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(serverUrl)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        Log.e("wingoku", "url is: "+ serverUrl);

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }
```

This is the code for parsing the okhttp response:

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {
                String serverResponse = response.body().string();
              }
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: try debug for response in the in in built class of OKHttp. I also faced this kind of issue with Volley and when I debugged in those classes I found the real error

Comment: I have tried it and for some odd reason it returns 404 using okhttp but it works great on the browsers

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with heroku server may be. But I am not quite sure since I don't have much experience with it. The urls open fine in the browser but it returns 404 with okhttp on android. I am going to keep digging but if someone has information regarding this, it will be very helpful

Comment: I would suggest to hit this api using some other methods for eg using volley or normally with asynctask. It will clarify that whether or not it is a bug with okhttp library

Comment: I doubt it's a bug in okhttp library. I didn't get the time to try those things yet but I still think it's something related to header info that okhttp sends to heroku and heroku then neglects mobile request